# How to find the non repeating words from the strings?

Tags: python

A word have vowel letters and consonant.

- There should not be no two vowels together
- There should not be no two Cosants together
- "z" is an exception from that rule. z can be repeating together

For example, "man" are True, "king","horse" are False, "zzzz" is True

Code

```
input_str1 = 'man'
input_str2 = 'king'
input_str3 = 'zzzz'
input_str4 = 'horse'
test_list = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)] 
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

test_list  have full alphabets

Comment: What have you tried *after* this?

Comment: @Justin, input string i have splitted into lists, then i have done [1::2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regex solution:

```
   vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    def check_st(st):
        v, c = 0, 0
        for i in st:
            if i in vowels:
                if v:
                    return False
                v, c = 1, 0
            elif i == 'z':
                continue
            else:
                if c:
                    return False
                v, c = 0, 1
        return True
```

v is for vowels and c is for consonants

- If you have v then: v=1 and c=0
- If you have z then we don't care --> moving to next iteration
- else it must be c then: v=0 and c=1

Then in next iteration we are ensuring it is not the same kind (v or c)

Just a note:

If 'z' is a 'sequence breaker' then you should assign:

```
    elif i == 'z':
        v, c = 0, 0
```

Comment: can you explain?                 v, c = 0, 1
,                 v, c = 1, 0

Comment: Yes,
v is for vowels and c is for consonants.

Basically when you have v you want next to be c (vice versa).

Comment: where you checking continuous letters

Comment: no  two Cosants together,no two vowels together

Comment: can i ask how you become expert in algorithm? what was the approach? how you succeeded??

Comment: @Nons I'm not an 'expert' 
Just practice.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex in python with 2 negative lookaheads:

```sh
^(?i)(?!.*[aeiou]{2})(?!.*[^aeiouz]{2})[a-z]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZaZRE/1)

**RegEx Details**

- `^`: Start
- `(?i)`: Enable case ignore matching
- `(?!.*[aeiou]{2})`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have 2 vowels together
- `(?!.*[^aeiouz]{2})`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have 2 consonants together
- `[a-z]+`: Match 1+ English letters
- `$`: End

In Python use:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> rx = re.compile(r'^(?!.*[aeiou]{2})(?!.*[^aeiouz]{2})[a-z]+$', re.I)
>>> arr = ['man', 'king', 'horse', 'zzzz']
>>> [s for s in arr if rx.search(s)]
['man', 'zzzz']
```

Comment: can you do python native method